# Unable to change a Loading Variable, in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having a problem with a Loading Variable.

I have a Welcome Screen which gets through Firebase User I get the User UID and from a Collection, I get the field name.

So I have the following Code:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../widgets/app_drawer.dart';
import '../widgets/footer.dart';

class InitialScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/initial';  

  @override
  _InitialScreenState createState() => _InitialScreenState();
}



class _InitialScreenState extends State<InitialScreen> {
   final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    var _nombre;
    var _isLoading = false;

 **void inputData() async {
   try {
     setState(() {
       _isLoading = true;
     });
      final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();
      Firestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .document(user.uid)
          .get()
          .then((value) {
        setState(() {
          _nombre = value['nombre']; 
          _isLoading = false;       
        });
      });
       setState(() {
          _isLoading = false;
        });
   } catch (err) {
        print(err);
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
   }
  }**
  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    inputData();
    _isLoading = false;
    return  Scaffold(
      drawer: AppDrawer(),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Macabeos'),
      ),
      body: _isLoading ? Text(_nombre) : Container(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                      'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/flutter-chat-8b2e0.appspot.com/o/others%2Ftaber.png?alt=media&token=0381a057-bf69-4885-8690-f25e6f1abfe0'),
                  radius: 80.50,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                ),
              ),
              Divider(),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 60.0),
                child: Text(
                  'Bienvenido Hermano:',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                ),
              ),
              Divider(),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 60.0),
                child: Text(
                  _nombre,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 18,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Divider(),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 60.0),
                child: Text(
                    'Ha Ingresado a MacabeosApp, en esta app manejara su Servicio con el Ministerio Macabeos.',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Footer(),
    );
  }
}
```

I get the information with this Function:

```
void inputData() async {
   try {
     setState(() {
       _isLoading = true;
     });
      final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();
      Firestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .document(user.uid)
          .get()
          .then((value) {
        setState(() {
          _nombre = value['nombre']; 
          _isLoading = false;       
        });
      });
       setState(() {
          _isLoading = false;
        });
   } catch (err) {
        print(err);
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
   }
  }
```

And then called in the Build to fill the information and fill the Text Widget with the Name Variable (_nombre).

The problem that I get is:

***════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building InitialScreen(dirty, state: _InitialScreenState#1f7ab):
A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':
Failed assertion: line 360 pos 10: 'data != null'***

[image]

And when I checked where the issue is, I found it is on the Text Widget, And I assume the issue is that it is loading from Firebase the information and it is still not ready, and it displays a red screen but in 5 seconds it takes it away.

I used the **_isLoading** variable to check if it is performing the information reception from Firebase, and I wish to display a Circular Progress Bar while the information is being filled, or in the worst case at least not display the red screen, anything I could do?

**FYI this red screen displays for just like 2 seconds or 5 seconds tops then everything loads correctly**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**: I managed to fix it as it seems that during Initial Build the app wa looking for a value on the text from Firebase so I just put in Init State to equal the string to say Loading and it worked.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are not using the CircularProgressIndicator and you are not actually using the _isLoading correctly.

`body: _isLoading ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()) : Container(...)`

This is how you have to use the Progress Indicator.
The above code renders a ***Text*** widget and the data is passed after some time, that is why the red screen.

You should also remove the _isLoading from the build method. It is of no use.

Comment: Hi, 

My idea for _isLoading is to be a Flag, basically what I want is that during the loading process of filling the variable the value changes to True, and once it has loaded is False, so what I try to do on that line is check if _isLoading is true display the progress indicator, and if it is false load the container.

Comment: Yes, i understand that. You need to use it properly as I mentioned above. When the loading is true, it will display the progress indicator, until we have the values from Firebase. Try this once.

Comment: Hey I tried it again, and still get the same error after doing the change: 

 body: _isLoading ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()) : Container(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,

I added a bit more code just to show the change, however it still displays the red screen for a second and never shows the circular progresses indicator.